# Flickering NSTextFields

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I have two NSTextFields in a xib file I'm using to display some preferences to users.

There is a save button that I wanted to be unusable until these preferences have been filled out. For some reason, this made all the NSTextFields in the xib file totally unusable as well (it was as if they had been disabled).

When I enable the NSButton, everything works--but with a catch. Whenever I focus the cursor or type in one of the NSTextFields, the text inside flickers. It's really disconcerting.

There's no custom code powering the UI elements.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please describe how you are enabling/disabling the button in response to changes in the text fields.

Comment: I enable the button when the text fields have content.

Comment: Right, but you say there's no code behind them, so are you binding the fields to UserDefaults or something? Are you sure you haven't enabled Core Animation layer-backing somewhere?

Comment: Nope, they're not bound to UserDefaults, and I'm not using CALayers to render the fields, or anything weird like that. Maybe a video would help?

Comment: I'll also see if I can reproduce the issue with a barebones project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though this is a bug in Interface Builder.

After deleting the NSTextFields that were flickering and adding them back in IB, the flickering stopped.